# How do I know when child element has finished rendering in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a layout component that has a `<router-outlet>` in which child components are dynamically inserted by the router.

How do I know, when child element is inserted and is finished constructing it's view?

Also, I can't fire events from child components manually, because I want this solution to be generic.

Comment: have you checked ngafterviewinit inside child component

Comment: What do you mean by "checked"? How do I know if it was called from parent component?

Comment: `<router-outlet (activate)="onActivated($event)"></router-outlet>`

Comment: I mean have seen ngafterviewinit topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind to the `<router-outlet>` component using `@ViewChild` binding.

For any component that uses a `<router-outlet>` add this:

```
/**
 * Gain access to the inner route child.
 */
@ViewChild(RouterOutlet)
public outlet: RouterOutlet;
```

You can then listen for changes like this:

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.outlet.activateEvents.subscribe((component) => {
         // gets passed the new child component instance
    });
    this.outlet.deactivateEvents.subscribe(() => {
         // the child component has been destroyed
    });
    if (this.outlet.isActivated) {
        // will be false if there is no child route active
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've settled with this approach. It works great for my use case. And I better prefer to use `@ViewChild`, than to use `(activate)` binding.

Comment: @SlavaFominII https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3038-eventemitter-is-an-rxjs-observable-stream-in-angular-2-beta-6.htm#comments_47949

Answer (score 4):

Router calls `activateWith` method on the `router-outlet` which creates a `componentRef` and attaches it to the `router-outlet` container. Then it emits `activate` event:

```
this.activateEvents.emit(this.activated.instance);
```

At this point the view for the component is created and attached to the DOM. However only the `constructor` of the attached component is executed. No lifecycle hooks yet. During next change detection the lifecycle hooks of the attached components will be called.

You can subscribe to this event through `(activate)` output as yurzui showed:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivated($event)"></router-outlet>
```

or using event emitter, which is not recommended:

```
this.outlet.activateEvents.subscribe((component) => {
      this.activated = true; 
});
```

So if, for example, you want to know when `ngOnInit` has been called for the child component, you can do something like this:

```
const activated = false;

onActivated() {
   this.activated = true; 
});

ngAfterViewInit() {
   if (this.activated) {
     // lifecycle hooks for the child component have been called
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it's a reasonable solution. However, I've decided to use `@ViewChild` approach, because it will allow to isolate the functionality inside of a single function, without adding extra code to the template.

Comment: @SlavaFominII, if you simply use the approach by ThinkingMedia, the lifecycle hooks will not have been called in the `activateEvents.subscribe(()=> { // gets passed the new child component instance`. But my solution does that. It actually doesn't much matter how to subscribe to the activated event, what's important is this logic `ngAfterViewInit() {
   if (this.activated) {`. I think that Angular doesn't encourage subscribing to the event emitter directly

Comment: Actually, I'm using this solution, based on the answer by ThinkingMedia and it works great: https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/dc53ae995a449e13807217ae0b582c27